# SOLR - Order facet values case-insentive while preserving the original value in facet result

Tags: solr

I am querying a facet field which looks like this:

```
<field name="brand" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false />
```

The `string` type definition:

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true"/>
```

I sort the facet values based on `index`: `f.brand.facet.sort=index`.

This gives me a result like this:

```
Aaaa (5)
Bbbb (14
Cccc (8)
abbb (29)
```

I would like to sort the values case-insensitive, so I tried to make a new `fieldType` using `LowerCaseFilterFactory`:

```
<fieldType name="text_facet" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

After reindexing the result looks like this:

```
aaaa (5)
abbb (29)
bbbb (14)
cccc (8)
```

The order is correct, but the values are now LowerCase as well.

I would like this result:

```
Aaaa (5)
abbb (29)
Bbbb (14)
Cccc (8)
```

Most posts here tell me to create a `copyField`, but I don't understand how I can combine the two fields when it comes to facet-queries.

Is there a way to sort facet values case-insensitive while preserving the original value when querying it?

Comment: Are you always retrieving all the facet entries? I.e. could you sort client side?

Comment: @MatsLindh No, I'm not. I'm looking for a elegant way to let Solr handle the sorting.

Comment: Then I don't think you'll have a perfect solution using only Solr faceting (hacking something together with streaming expressions might be possible). Payloads with faceting could perhaps solve this, but that hasn't been implemented in any form at the moment .. Another option is to prefix your values with the lowercased form and a separator (i.e. index `aaaa;Aaaa` and `bbbb;Bbbb`, then split by that separator in your frontend. This would give different counts for different casing, but that might not be an issue / might be desired anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is no straight way of doing this. I think the proposal to use `copyField` is something else, but I potentially, it could help.

The idea is following: you create *brand* field of type `string`, than you have `copyField` with lowercasing.

```
<field name="brand" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<field name="brand_text" type="text_facet" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true"/>

<fieldType name="text_facet" class="solr.TextField">
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<copyField source="brand" dest="brand_text" />
```

During query time, you just query both fields for faceting - in your case it will be something like this (I've added some documents):

```
brand:[Aaaa (1), Bbbb (1), Cccc (1), aBbb (1), abbb (1)]
brand_text:[aaaa (1), abbb (2), bbbb (1), cccc (1)]
```

As soon as you get sorting by `brand_text`, you could get the original facet values and somehow provide proper response.

However, I want to point out, that similar lowercased values could be mixed. In our case it's both `ABbb` and `abbb` that are exactly the same in the lowercase mode, so the question is, what you want to show there, so I think it should be properly handled on the business logic side.

Completely correct solution could be achieved by extending `org.apache.solr.handler.component.FacetComponent`, which is responsible for Solr faceting. There is a code, which is doing sorting:

```
      boolean countSorted = dff.sort.equals(FacetParams.FACET_SORT_COUNT);
      if (countSorted) {
        counts = dff.countSorted;
        if (counts == null || dff.needRefinements) {
          counts = dff.getCountSorted();
        }
      } else if (dff.sort.equals(FacetParams.FACET_SORT_INDEX)) {
        counts = dff.getLexSorted();
      } else { // TODO: log error or throw exception?
        counts = dff.getLexSorted();
      }
```

and `getLexSorted` is exactly what is sorting the terms:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, (o1, o2) -> o1.indexed.compareTo(o2.indexed));
```

and you just need to apply `toLowerCase()` to both `o1` and `o2`. However, this approach will be much harder - you need to implement (extend existing FacetComponent and later enable it in your solrconfig.xml, including CI, etc, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this is exactly what I was thinking. Combining the 2 different facet-fields is subject to errors and does not scale well (since I would either keep track of the original brand name or would have to query ALL facet values). I don't think it is feasible for me to extend the `FacetComponent` class, but will take a look at it since it looks like it is the most elegant way.

Comment: @Rob, unfortunately, that's the only possibility to deal on the Solr side. Usually, you just need to keep brand names (just as an example) consistent across whole catalog in some preferred form.

Comment: There really is no way to keep brand names consistent since they are names and I can't just start CamelCasing a trademarked name.